# Odoo 10 - Weight and volume in product template, what happens when sold with UOM?

Tags: odoo

I define a product to be purchased in `units` but sold in `boxes of 500 units`.

What `weight` and `volume` represent in product_template?

Do they represent the weight and volume of a single unit or the weight and volume of the 500 units?

Answer (score 0):

Weight and Volume is used for the delivery (carrier) , when you create delivery from sales order , total weight will be calculated for the delivery.

Comment: Ok, but the question is specific to weight/volume relation to UOM. When you are using a selling UOM of 500 units and a purchase UOM of 1 unit, does weight and volume refer to 500 units UOM or to single unit UOM?

Comment: It refers to a single unit , that will multiply with quantity * unit weight

Comment: I am getting different answer in Odoo forum https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/odoo-10-weight-and-volume-in-product-template-what-happens-when-sold-with-uom-123661

Comment: I still believe it is not related to unit of measure any how.

Comment: Thanks I will do some tests then to clarify.